# how to solve netflix eureka client error in spring boot 3.2.0 and java 17

Tags: java, spring-boot, netflix-eureka

I am trying to configure eureka client in my new spring boot 3.2.0 application using java 17 and getting the below error while running.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.eurekaClient' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/netflix/eureka/EurekaClientAutoConfiguration$RefreshableEurekaClientConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'eurekaClient' parameter 3: No qualifying bean of type 'com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.jersey.TransportClientFactories<?>' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
```

[image]

I am using the below maven dependency and no other configurations.

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
   <version>4.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Please note that if I remove this dependency I don't see any error.\

Main Class

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringBoot3Java17Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(CommissionManagerApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

application.properties: (and also need help in how the application tracks the eureka server running locally)

```
eureka.client.service-url.defaultZone=http://admin:alined@localhost:8761/eureka/
```

Application Started but not registering with Eureka:
[image]

Eureka Server:
[image]

Need assistance in configuring eureka netflix client with spring boot 3.2.0 and java 17

Thank you!

Answer (score 8):

I had the same issue when I upgraded to Spring Boot 3.2.1 and Spring Cloud Dependencies 2023.0.0.
I managed to solve the issue by adding the following dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.netflix.eureka</groupId>
    <artifactId>eureka-client-jersey3</artifactId>
 </dependency>
```

and creating the following bean:

```
import com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.jersey3.Jersey3TransportClientFactories;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class Jersey3TransportClientFactoriesConfig {

    @Bean
    public Jersey3TransportClientFactories jersey3TransportClientFactories() {
        return new Jersey3TransportClientFactories();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

solve this issue by adding this dependacy

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```